# Pointer to a IMAGE_NT_HEADERS(masm32)

Tags: assembly, masm32

I came across the following lines of code:

assume esi:ptr IMAGE_NT_HEADERS

lea esi,[esi].OptionalHeader

and for the second day I can’t figure it out:
1.why you don’t need to specify the data type before ptr here.

2.why assume with ptr is used here.  I read that this directive requires a data type, but I don't quite understand how it works.  I studied masm on a dos system, and there this directive connected two registers, what it does here - I do not quite understand.

Why can't you just refer to IMAGE_NT_HEADERS as:

lea esi, [IMAGE_NT_HEADERS].OptionalHeader

in Windows, a flat model is used and there is no need to bind segment registers and IMAGE_NT_HEADERS is a regular  structure or did I misunderstand?

Comment: You can have the assembler show you the difference: Write it one way, then write it the other way, and compare the output.

Comment: `ASSUME` as used here just tells MASM that `esi` points to a structure of type `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` so you can use the syntax `[esi].OptionalHeader` instead of a magic constant `[esi+xx]`. See [this](http://www.asmcommunity.net/forums/topic/?id=10551). This has nothing to do with segmentation, the `PTR` after `ASSUME` is what makes the difference.

Comment: @MargaretBloom 
ok, I understand that, but why is it not necessary to specify the data type before ptr? if it automatically assigns it, which one?

Comment: @Jekgley [`IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` is a type](https://www.nirsoft.net/kernel_struct/vista/IMAGE_NT_HEADERS.html). The syntax is `ASSUME <register>: PTR <type>`.

Comment: The [MASM grammar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/masm-bnf-grammar?view=msvc-170) says the syntax is `ASSUME assumeList` where `assumeList` is a list of `assumeReg`, and `assumeReg` is `register : assumeVal`. `assumeVal` is either a `qualifiedType` or the magic words `ERROR` or `NONE`. A `qualifiedType` is either a `type` or an optional distance, then the magic word `PTR`, and then another optional `qualifiedType`. In `assume esi:ptr IMAGE_NT_HEADERS`, `esi` is the `register` and `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` is the `type`. You are in fact required to put the `PTR` before the type.

Comment: You can learn a lot from reading the documentation. If you want to know what syntax is legal, look at the grammar.